# Send an email to multiple contacts, asking to confirm information that we have on SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, updatelistitems, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-email, microsoft-flow

I am trying to send an automated custom email (via Flow or directly via SharePoint; no SharePoint Designer, PowerApps, or anything of the like). We can only use SharePoint Online. These emails would be sent to a contact based on the list.

The list columns look something like this:

**Contact List**

Operator First Name  **|**  Operator Last Name  |  Email  |  Entity Name  |  FEIN  |  Date

I would like for the email to pull each contact and its respected entity names, FEIN, and date (the red in the photo below).

The end goal is to have the operator confirm that this is the most recent info. If it is wrong, they would have the option of editing that list item. NOTE: since this email would be sent out to hundreds of people, *it is vital that they do not have access to view other people's information.*

This email would be sent on the same day every year (let's say January 15th). There would be a follow up email on February 1st.

If the email could look something like the below photo, that would be fantastic. Nothing fancy necessary at the moment. I just do not want to call/send emails to 500+ contacts.

Also, my department is very limited on what we can or cannot do in SharePoint (no PowerApps, no Microsoft Forms, no SharePoint Designer, limited use for Microsoft Access).

[image]

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had similar requirements for a Flow except we generate a csv to send to each contact. This csv can then be imported back into the list. Alternatively, if you want users to update the list themselves, you have to consider security. The only way to lock down list items per user is by going to Library Settings => Advanced Settings:

[image]

Here is the Flow, you can copy this structure. If you want to embed the table rather than attach a csv, you can swap the action 'Create CSV Table' with 'Create HTML table' and add the Output of that action to the Body of 'Send an email'

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - thank you! This helped a ton!

Comment: Good to hear, mark it as the answer so people know it works!

Comment: Just to clarify, what did you write in your condition string in this flow? I cannot seem to get it to work anymore...

Comment: @gjustyna2, the condition = string('value')